# How to display SVG image after clicking on submit button in PHP?

Tags: php, html, css, forms

I want to display svg image and text after submitting the contact form but i don't have any experience in php, So can you guys help out in this problem. Right now after submitting the form it's simply display "Your message has been sent successfully" after clicking the submit button.

See the attached image which i want to display [Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Chgat.png)

```
 <form id="contact-form"  action="formProcess.php">
    <ul class="contact-inputs">
       <li><input type="text" name="your_name" id="name" placeholder="Name"></li>
       <li><input type="email" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Email"></li>
       <li><input type="text" name="subject" id="subject" placeholder="Subject"></li>
       <li><textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="5" placeholder="Message"></textarea></li>
       <li class="send-btn"><button type="submit" id="submit">Send</button></li>
     </ul>
 </form>







 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#submit').click(function(e){

            e.preventDefault();

            var name = $("#name").val();

            var email = $("#email").val();

            var subject = $("#subject").val();

            var message = $("#message").val();

            $.ajax({

                type: "POST",

                url: "formProcess.php",

                dataType: "json",

                data: {name:name, email:email, subject:subject, message:message},

                success : function(data){

                    if (data.code == "200"){

                        //alert("Success: " +data.msg);

                        $(".display-error").html(data.msg);

                        $(".display-error").css("display","block");

                        $("#contact-form").css("display","none");

                    } else {

                        $(".display-error").html("<ul>"+data.msg+"</ul>");

                        $(".display-error").css("display","block");

                    }

                }

            });

        });

    });
</script>



<?php

    $errorMSG = "";


    /* NAME */

    if (empty($_POST["name"])) {

        $errorMSG = "<li>Name is required</li>";

    } else {

        $name = $_POST["name"];

    }


    /* EMAIL */

    if (empty($_POST["email"])) {

        $errorMSG .= "<li>Email is required</li>";

    } else if(!filter_var($_POST["email"], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {

        $errorMSG .= "<li>Invalid email format</li>";

    }else {

        $email = $_POST["email"];

    }


    /* SUBJECT */

    if (empty($_POST["subject"])) {

        $errorMSG .= "<li>Subject is required</li>";

    } else {

        $subject = $_POST["subject"];

    }


    /* MESSAGE */

    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {

        $errorMSG .= "<li>Message is required</li>";

    } else {

        $message = $_POST["message"];

    }

    if(empty($errorMSG)) {

        // Set the recipient email address.
        // FIXME: Update this to your desired email address.
        $recipient = "umerzamanlive@gmail.com";

        // Set the email subject.
        $subject = "New contact from $name";

        // Build the email content.
        $email_content = "Name: $name\n";
        $email_content .= "Email: $email\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Subject: $subject\n\n";
        $email_content .= "Message:\n$message\n";

        // Build the email headers.
        $email_headers = "From: $name <$email>";

        (mail($recipient, $subject, $email_content, $email_headers));

        $success .= "Your message has been sent successfully";
        echo json_encode(['code'=>200, 'msg'=>$success]);

        exit;

    }

    echo json_encode(['code'=>404, 'msg'=>$errorMSG]);
```

Comment: This is more a HTML 'problem' than a PHP problem. See: https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/

Comment: Can you post the REAL code? What you have here does not display anything, because the text is commented out and the img has `..` for a source. And the svg you want to display is a png file. And there's no check if the mail has been sent successfully!

Comment: @KIKO Software, @ Mr Lister, I just updated the code. Check it and lemme know